# Java: Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?VALUES ('23')' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to update my database table but I have encountered a MySQLSyntaxErrorException. May I know how can I solve this error?

Thanks ! :)

```
//Retrieve data from database
  String queryy = "SELECT agent.agentID, agent.agentEmail, departmentName FROM agent JOIN department ON agentEmail = email";
  rs = myStat.executeQuery(queryy);

//Iterate the result set and get one row at a time
  while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("agentID");
    email = rs.getString("agentEmail");
    String emaill = email;
    departmentName = rs.getString("departmentName");
    String departmentNamee = departmentName;

    System.out.println("Agent ID = " + id);
    System.out.println("Department Name = " + departmentNamee);
    System.out.println("Email = " + emaill + newLine);

//Update agentID in department table from agent table
    String departmentUpdateSql = "UPDATE department SET agentID = ?"
                            + "VALUES ('" + id +"')";
    myStat.executeUpdate(departmentUpdateSql);'
```

And this is the error that I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?VALUES ('23')' at line 1
```

Comment: Hmm, I still got the same error tho :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql `update` statements do not use the `VALUES` keyword (that is for inserts)

Use a PreparedStatement as below

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE department  SET agentID = ?"
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
       dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);

// execute update SQL stetement
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

**Note**

I would imagine that you would also need some kind of where clause otherwise you will be updating **all** records

Comment: This would set the agentID for all the rows of the table, something OP might not want to do.